# Dynamically building command line arguments and values with spaces

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I have the following 2 scripts:

`main.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG_WITH_SPACES="this is a value with spaces"
COMPOSITE_ARGS="-p $ARG_WITH_SPACES"

echo "main.sh will run:"
echo "  ./child.sh $COMPOSITE_ARGS"
./child.sh $COMPOSITE_ARGS
```

and `child.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "child.sh received:"
echo "  1: $1"
echo "  2: $2"
```

If I run `main.js` I get:

```
main.sh will run:
  ./child.sh -p "this is a value with spaces"
child.sh received:
  1: -p
  2: "this
```

I am trying to understand why `$2` in `child.sh` is `"this` and not `this is a value with spaces`. What I want to achieve is passing values with spaces through multiple scripts through parameters and I don't get the quoting right.

1. Deleting the escaped quoted from `COMPOSITE_ARGS` makes no sense to me because that will generate the split.
2. Putting quotes around `$COMPOSITE_ARGS` makes no sense because that will merge both `-p` and `"this is a value with spaces"` into one argument.

Any ideas? What I want to achieve is:

```
main.sh will run:
  ./child.sh -p "this is a value with spaces"
child.sh received:
  1: -p
  2: this is a value with spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array or else as you observed each argument will be split on spaces:

```
$ arg="hello world"
$ arg2="john doe"
$ comp_args=("-l" "$arg" "$arg2");
$ ls "${comp_args[@]}"
ls: cannot access hello world: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access john doe: No such file or directory
```

Hope you get the point.

In your example:

```
ARG_WITH_SPACES="this is a value with spaces"
COMPOSITE_ARGS=("-p" "$ARG_WITH_SPACES")

bash child.sh "${COMPOSITE_ARGS[0]}"
```